# Trying to install Rails, Failed to Build Gem Native Extension

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to install Rails on Ubuntu 12.10 using the Ruby Version Manager. I believe that Ruby and RubyGems are installed correctly, and these are my versions:

```
ruby -v: ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [x86_64-linux]
gem -v: 1.8.23
```

I'm trying to install rails, using

```
sudo gem install rails -v 3.2.9
```

This fetches a lot of gems, but has a problem building the native extensions:

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 extconf.rb
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- mkmf (LoadError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from extconf.rb:1:in `<main>'

Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.7.5 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.7.5/ext/json/ext/generator/gem_make.out
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? If it helps, I'm trying to follow the tutorial at http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book#sec-install_rails.

Thank you!

Comment: maybe "sudo gem install rails -v 3.2.9 --trace" got more informations for us. But installing a compiler sounds good to me ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install the gem as a normal user, not sudo:

> gem install rails

Or install the ruby dev package. There are a lot of similar answers in SO:

[Failed to build gem native extension — Rails install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12552929/failed-to-build-gem-native-extension-rails-install#12552948)

[Unable to install gem - Failed to build gem native extension - cannot load such file -- mkmf (LoadError)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13767725/unable-to-install-gem-failed-to-build-gem-native-extension-cannot-load-such)

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a C compiler installed? If not, you should run `sudo apt-get install build-essential` to set up a compiler toolchain