# Unable to install gem - Failed to build gem native extension - cannot load such file -- mkmf (LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, rubygems, bcrypt

Ruby 1.9.3

The part of Gemfile

```
#...............
gem "pony"
gem "bcrypt-ruby", :require => "bcrypt"
gem "nokogiri" 
#..................
```

When I'm trying to install gems, I get an error

```
alex@ubuntu:~/$ bundle
Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/.........
Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/..
Enter your password to install the bundled RubyGems to your system: 
#####............................................................
Installing bcrypt-ruby (3.0.1) with native extensions 
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 extconf.rb 
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- mkmf (LoadError)
        from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
        from extconf.rb:36:in `<main>'


Gem files will remain installed in /home/alex/.bundler/tmp/5526/gems/bcrypt-ruby-3.0.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/alex/.bundler/tmp/5526/gems/bcrypt-ruby-3.0.1/ext/mri/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing bcrypt-ruby (3.0.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install bcrypt-ruby -v '3.0.1'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Then I'm doing this

```
sudo gem install bcrypt-ruby -v '3.0.1'
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing bcrypt-ruby:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 extconf.rb
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- mkmf (LoadError)
        from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
        from extconf.rb:36:in `<main>'


Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bcrypt-ruby-3.0.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bcrypt-ruby-3.0.1/ext/mri/gem_make.out
```

and getting an error as well.

What did I miss?

Comment: possible duplicate of [\`require': no such file to load -- mkmf (LoadError)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7645918/require-no-such-file-to-load-mkmf-loaderror)

Comment: For macOS, this might be helpful as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20939568/error-error-installing-cocoapods-error-failed-to-build-gem-native-extension

Answer (score 473, accepted):

There are similar questions:

- [`require': no such file to load -- mkmf (LoadError)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7645918/require-no-such-file-to-load-mkmf-loaderror)
- [Failed to build gem native extension (mkmf (LoadError)) - Ubuntu 12.04](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18316667/failed-to-build-gem-native-extension-mkmf-loaderror-ubuntu-12-04/18316692#18316692)

Usually, the solution is:

```
sudo apt-get install ruby-dev
```

**Or, if that doesn't work, depending on your ruby version**, run something like:

```
sudo apt-get install ruby1.9.1-dev
```

Should fix your problem.

---

Still not working? Try the following after installing ruby-dev:

```
sudo apt-get install make
```

Comment: But I have 1.9.3 ruby only.

Comment: ruby 1.9.3 is an alias of ruby 1.9.1

Comment: After installing `ruby1.9.1-dev` I had to also `sudo apt-get install make`. Thank you!

Comment: If you have installed your ruby with command `sudo apt-get install ruby` (without specifying the version) then you don't need to worry about your version too much if you just install `sudo apt-get install ruby-dev`

Comment: Thank you @wasatchwizard, after doing what you suggested it worked for me :)

Comment: Worked for me, thanks. But I did end up running bundle install as sudo.

Comment: Thanks - using `sudo apt-get install make` finally did the trick for me, after I found the first part of your solution elsewhere.

Comment: I found that on Ubuntu 16.04 you also need `sudo apt-get install gcc make`

Comment: I am getting this error:

    sudo: apt-get: command not found

can I install it with brew ?

Answer (score 30):

For WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux) you need install `build-essential` package:

```
sudo apt install build-essential
```

Comment: Solved it for me after none of the other suggestions seemed to do it. My setup: Win10 Pro + WSL with Ubuntu 18.04 + Ruby 2.5. Thanks!

Comment: Same thing for an Ubuntu Server Hyper-V VM.

Comment: Worked for me on Ubuntu within Docker

Comment: This worked for me on a regular install of Ubuntu 18.04 LTS when trying to install Typhoeus. Took ages to get there, thanks!

Comment: im not a ruby guy so im totally mystified as to why this is required to install a simple gem, but im thankful for this answer. was exactly the issue for me

Answer (score 15):

For MacOS users:

Just do this and easily it will solve your problem:

```
brew install cocoapods
```

Answer (score 12):

Just finished a 2 hour wild goose chase trying to solve this. None of the posted answers worked for me. Im on a Mac (Mojave Version 10.14.6, Xcode Version 11.3).

It turns out the ruby file headers were missing so i had to run `open /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Packages/macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS_10.14.pkg`

That didnt work for me at first because the version of CommandLineTools i had installed did not have the "Packages" folder. So i uninstalled and reinstalled like this:

`rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools`

`xcode-select --install`

Then i ran the previous command again:

`open /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Packages/macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS_10.14.pkg`

After install the error was fixed!

Comment: This worked for me. I'm on macOS 10.14.6 (18G1012). Xcode 11.3.

Comment: Thanks. Your solution worked for me when installing "sudo gem install cocoapods" for flutter development.

Comment: I don't get 'Packages/' folder after reinstalling.

Answer (score 10):

I had the same issue trying to install jquery-rails. The fix was

```
sudo apt-get install zlibc zlib1g zlib1g-dev
```

Comment: Just installing `zlib1g-dev` will give you what you need here, or at least it did for me.

Answer (score 7):

In case anyone in the future had this problem, I'm using a Mac and just had to install the Command Line Tools using 'xcode-select --install'

Comment: This worked for me. In my case, I was scratching my head because my build was working fine until I upgraded to El Capitan.

Answer (score 6):

I found that I needed to install another version of ruby. So running the command

```
$ sudo apt-get install ruby1.9.1-dev
```

and then attempt to install the extension

If you run into issues where it is telling you that you don't have g++ you can run the following command to install it

```
$ sudo apt-get install g++
```

Answer (score 5):

1. Make sure `ruby-dev` is installed
2. Make sure `make` is installed
3. If you still get the error, look for suggested packages.  If you are trying to install something like `gem install pg` you will also need to install the lib `libpq-dev` (`sudo apt-get install libpq-dev`).

Answer (score 5):

I created a small hackMD to install cocoapods on MacOS 10.15 (Catalina) and 11 (Big Sur)

https://hackmd.io/@sBJPlhRESGqCKCqV8ZjP1A/S1UY3W7HP

## Installing Cocoapods on MacOS Catalina(MacOS 10.15.X) and Big Sur (MacOS 11)

1. Make sure you have xcode components are installed.
2. Download 'Command Line Tools' (about 500MB) directly from this link (Requires you to have apple account)
   https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action
3. Install the downloaded file
4. Click on Install
5. Install COCOAPODS files in terminal
   `sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods`

Comment: `brew install cocoapods` worked for me (assuming you have brew installed and up to date)

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me.

`bundle config --global build.snappy --with-opt-dir="$(brew --prefix snappy)"`

Answer (score 1):

It also helps to ensure libmysqlclient-dev is installed (Ubuntu 14.04)

Answer (score 1):

What ended up working for me after a few hours of pain..

if you're running brew..

```
brew install ruby
```

in the terminal output/log, identify the path where ruby was installed, brew suggests 'You may want to add this to your PATH', so that's what we'll do. For example, mine is

```
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/bin
```

Add this to your path by running (omitting braces)

```
echo 'export PATH"{the_path_you_found_above}:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

then update your environment by running

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

now, try running your install, i.e.,

```
sudo gem install middleman
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are a mac user you must need to update the clang version being used
I burnt hours searching this and installed uninstalled xcode commandline tools but it didn't help.
I ran `gcc -v` and `Apple clang version 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.8` was the output.
Then I ran `xcode-select -s /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/` and clang version was updated to `Apple clang version 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.29)`.
bundle install was successful after that.
I hope this may help.

Answer (score 1):

I was making a [word search](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=word.search.sopa.deletras) app and I had to install cocoapods and after formatting my mac and reinstalling xcode, I still got the error when I wanted to install cocoapods.

And the solution for this was the following:

It looks like CocoaPods 1.9.0, the latest version as of this writing, depends on a newer version of Ruby than 2.3.7. But macOS Mojave only includes Ruby 2.3.7, so you have a few different options.

```
    Upgrade to macOS Catalina and get Ruby 2.6.3
    Use Ruby Version Manager to install a newer version of Ruby
    Install an older version of CocoaPods
    sudo gem install cocoapods -v 1.8.4
```

I did 3:

sudo gem install cocoapods -v 1.8.4

Answer (score 1):

first set your Xcode version on the terminal:

```
sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app
```

then install:

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

Comment: It works for me on Macbook m1 pro Sonoma 14.0

Answer (score 0):

In Mac, for me this works:

```
CONFIGURE_OPTS="--enable-shared" rbenv install 2.2.2
```

Answer (score 0):

After some search for a solution, it turns out the -dev package is needed, not just ruby1.8. So if you have ruby1.9.1 doing

```
sudo apt-get install ruby1.9.1-dev
```

or to install generic ruby version, use (as per @lamplightdev comment):

```
sudo apt-get install ruby-dev
```

should fix it.

Try to locate mkmf to see if the file is actually there.