# Error installing rails: Error building native extension (-Wl insilde ld call)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haiku

Currently I'm trying to install rails on Haiku R1 aplha 4 OS.

I must warn you that I'm very new to Haiku and ruby as well.
I have failed to find posts with similar problem and I'm terribly sorry if I was wrong and such topic already exists.

**Steps:**

1. I have installed ruby 1.9.1 with [haikuporter](http://ports.haiku-files.org/wiki/Installation)
2. Then executed *gem update --system* //Everything seems ti be fine
3. Finally *gem install rails*

**Output:**

> Fetching ...
>
> Fetching bla bla bla
>
> Fetching: json-1.7.6.gem (100%)
>
> Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
>
> ERROR:  Error installing rails:
>          ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
>
> ```
>    /boot/common/bin/ruby extconf.rb
> ```
>
> creating Makefile
>
> make
>   gcc -I. -I/boot/common/include/ruby-1.9.1/i586-haiku -I/boot/common/include/ruby-> 1.9.1/ruby/backward -I/boot/common/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I. -DJSON_GENERATOR    -O2 -g -Wall -Wno-parentheses -O3 -Wall -O0 -ggdb  -o generator.o -c generator.c
>
> ld -shared -o generator.so generator.o -L. -L/boot/common/lib -Wl,-R/boot/common/lib -L.  -L/boot/develop/lib/x86 -lroot -L/boot/common/lib
>
> ld: unrecognized option '-Wl,-R/boot/common/lib'
>   ld: use the --help option for usage information
>
> make: *** [generator.so] Error 1

I investigated here. -Wl option is used when we want to call linker indirectly (for example from gcc call).

ld doesn't have -Wl, so it seems that error is obvious - we don't need -Wl inside ld call.

Then I asked myself "Ok, you have possible solution - just to remove this -Wl, but where this script is located?" I have no idea where to look =(

Also problem may be not so obvious and I should do smth complicated (including ritual dancing)

So, I figured out that I need help with this, otherwise I would spent the entire life sitting with clever face in front of monitor.

Please, any suggestions? Where I was wrong?

Comment: Is this still an issue? Haiku's Ruby port on the nightly images is much improved.

Comment: i think you should try installing json pure  gem(https://rubygems.org/gems/json_pure)

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a duplciate of this issue:

[Failed to build gem native extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13767725/unable-to-install-gem-failed-to-build-gem-native-extension-cannot-load-such/13767801#13767801)

So, try installing either

```
ruby-dev
```

or

```
ruby1.9.1-dev
```