# Error installing rails on Ubuntu 12.04 (Failed to build gem native extension)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to install rails on ubuntu 12.04 but I'm having some issues

I tried

```
sudo gem install rails --pre
```

and got

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 extconf.rb
extconf.rb:13:in `require': cannot load such file -- mkmf (LoadError)
from extconf.rb:13:in `<main>'


Gem files will remain installed in /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/atomic-1.1.10 for   inspection.
Results logged to /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/atomic-1.1.10/ext/gem_make.out
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [\`require': no such file to load -- mkmf (LoadError)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7645918/require-no-such-file-to-load-mkmf-loaderror)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to install gem - Failed to build gem native extension - cannot load such file -- mkmf (LoadError)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13767725/unable-to-install-gem-failed-to-build-gem-native-extension-cannot-load-such)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because when you installed Ruby you did not install the build tools as well.

I wrote [a blog post about installing Ruby + Rails on Ubuntu](http://ryanbigg.com/2010/12/ubuntu-ruby-rvm-rails-and-you/) that has helped out a lot of people, and will probably help you too.

Comment: Please include details here rather than just the link.

Comment: While this answer is almost a year old it would be helpful if you posted the essential parts of the answer here, on this site, or your post risks being deleted [See the FAQ where it mentions answers that are 'barely more than a link'.](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#deletion) You may still include the link if you wish, but only as a 'reference'. The answer should stand on its own without needing the link.

Comment: This link doesn't answer the question.