# Did I install Ruby 1.9.3 correctly on RHEL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, json, rhel

Before you say `yum -y install ruby193`...  I did that.

Please note that I am not a Ruby developer, but need this program as part of another developer's work via web services. (He is not available.) Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I attempted to install a library per instructions and got:

```
[root@ctbroker console]# gem install json -v '1.8.0'
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing json:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.  /opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/include/ruby.h
Gem files will remain installed in /opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/local/share/gems/gems/json-1.8.0 for inspection.
Results logged to /opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/local/share/gems/gems/json-1.8.0/ext/json/ext/generator/gem_make.out
```

I noticed that `ruby.h` is only on the machine at `/usr/lib64/ruby/1.8/x86_64-linux/ruby.h`.

What am I missing?

Comment: Is this related? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13767725/unable-to-install-gem-failed-to-build-gem-native-extension-cannot-load-such/13767801#13767801

Comment: What would the repository for that be?
     yum install ruby1.9.1-dev
    This system is receiving updates from Red Hat Subscription Management.
    rhel-6-server-cf-tools-1-rpms 2.8 kB     00:00
    rhel-6-server-optional-rpms   3.5 kB     00:00
    rhel-6-server-rhev-agent-rpms 3.1 kB     00:00
    rhel-6-server-rpms            3.7 kB     00:00
    Setting up Install Process
    No package ruby1.9.1-dev available.
    Error: Nothing to do

Comment: The machine is missing the development libraries for Ruby, which would include all the headers so @MrYoshiji's comment is correct. I'd use `yum search ruby | grep devel` to see if I could ferret out the correct name.

Comment: Maybe you can specify the ruby header path with the options, I remember that you can use argument like `--with-ruby-dir-option=<path>`

Comment: Or `sudo yum install ruby-devel` (use rvmsudo if you are using RVM)

Comment: Okay, so after MUCH research, it turns out that not only was MrYoshiji mostly right, it turns out that there were two versions of ruby on the machine.  And, many versions of gems.  This has caused great issues.  So, I am happy to give you credit, but the pain continues.  Is there a way to completely clean a machine of all ruby and all gems so that I may start over?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I was able to to fix this problem on my system by running:

```
sudo yum install ruby193-ruby-devel.x86_64
```

Answer (score 4):

*RHEL*`yum install scl-utils scl-utils-build`

*CENTOS*`yum install centos-release-SCL -y`

```
yum install ruby193 ruby193-ruby-devel augeas-devel libxml2-devel -y
scl enable ruby193 "ruby -v"
scl enable ruby193 "bash"
gem install json -v '1.8.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to install following packages first:

```sh
yum install ruby-devel.x86_64 libxslt-devel libxml2-devel
```

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Run below command on your terminal:

```
gpg --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys 409B6B1796C275462A1703113804BB82D39DC0E3
```

Step 2: Install RVM Development version on your system:

```
\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash
```

For Latest version of Ruby i.e. 2.2.1 follow below steps:

```
\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby
```

After this step you should see a message like:
To start using RVM you need to run `source /home/user_name/.rvm/scripts/rvm` in all your open shell windows, in rare cases you need to reopen all shell windows.

Step 3: Activate ruby using the message

```
Source /home/user_name/.rvm/scripts/rvm
```

Step 4: Check Ruby version

```
ruby --version
```

Step 5: Say thanks if it works ;)