# Ruby 'bundle install' error when following 'Heroku getting started': Failed to build gem native extension

Tags: ruby, heroku, rubygems

I followed [Heroku getting started](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-ruby) from the beginning up to 'bundle install' (step #declare-app-dependencies) and saw an error.  Some dependencies seem missing but I don't know how to find what they are.  Can anybody tell what I should do?

```
$ bundle install
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/...........
Resolving dependencies...
Using rake 10.3.2
Using i18n 0.6.9

Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/usr/bin/ruby2.0 extconf.rb 
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /usr/lib/ruby/include/ruby.h


Gem files will remain installed in /tmp/bundler20140919-3839-1mafrop/json-1.8.1/gems/json-1.8.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /tmp/bundler20140919-3839-1mafrop/json-1.8.1/gems/json-1.8.1/ext/json/ext/generator/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing json (1.8.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install json -v '1.8.1'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Environment =

1. linuxmint 64bit as VM guest
2. ruby 2.0.0p299 (2013-08-29) [x86_64-linux-gnu]
3. gem -v = 2.0.7
4. gem list --local = bundler (1.7.3), i18n (0.6.9), rake (10.3.2)
5. installed [Heroku Toolbelt](https://toolbelt.heroku.com/debian)
6. using the [example code](https://github.com/heroku/ruby-getting-started.git) as in the instructions

Comment: I tried to [install ruby-dev](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13767725/unable-to-install-gem-failed-to-build-gem-native-extension-cannot-load-such?rq=1) and the same error is still present.

Answer (score 0):

After hours of trial I could finally `bundle install`.  I did

```
sudo apt-get purge ruby*
sudo apt-get install ruby
sudo apt-get install ruby-dev
sudo gem install bundler
```

After these, `bundle install` passed json-1.8.1 without error.  Then error came

```
...
You need to install postgresql-server-dev-X.Y for building a server-side extension or libpq-dev for building a client-side application.
...
```

so I did

```
sudo apt-get install libpq-dev
```

Then `bundle install` again.  And it read `Your bundle is complete!`.

---

For your reference, I did the following as well.  I do not know if the [Heroku getting started](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-ruby) example really needs them.

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql postgresql-contrib
sudo apt-get install libmagickwand-dev python-dev
```