# Install error rb-inotify installation

Tags: ruby

I am trying to install rb-inotify with the following command

```
sudo gem install rb-inotify
```

and I got the following error

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rb-inotify:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 extconf.rb
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- mkmf (LoadError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from extconf.rb:4:in `<main>'


Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/ffi-1.8.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/ffi-1.8.1/ext/ffi_c/gem_make.out
```

any help would be appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 17):

Install the `ruby1.9.1-dev` package first by running

```
sudo apt-get install ruby1.9.1-dev
```

from the terminal. Then install `rb-inotify` as you were trying before (possibly with the addition of the `--version` flag?)

```
sudo gem install --version '~>0.9' rb-inotify
```

I've followed this process to fix a warning from Sass, and it worked for me.

This comes from the [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12552929/failed-to-build-gem-native-extension-rails-install/12552948#12552948) linked in the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16331294/install-error-rb-inotify-installation#comment23639859_16332180) by @shrikant1712. I'm merely typing it up here for easier access from this question.

Comment: I tried this ad am still getting the error... Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rb-inotify:
 ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 extconf.rb
checking for ffi.h... no
checking for ffi.h in /usr/local/include,/usr/include/ffi... no
checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... yes
checking for rb_thread_call_with_gvl()... yes
checking for rb_thread_call_without_gvl()... yes
checking for ffi_prep_cif_var()... no
creating extconf.h
creating Makefile

make
sh: 1: make: not found

Answer (score 1):

add into your gemfile as

```
gem "rb-inotify", "~> 0.9.0"
```

and `bundle install`

Comment: where is the gemfile location? Sorry I am new to Ruby.

Comment: gemfile is in your project root directory

Comment: so I don't have a project associated with the install, I was just trying to install rb-inotify for the general system environment...or is it not possible to do that?

Comment: checkout this link it might be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12552929/failed-to-build-gem-native-extension-rails-install