# Cant install SASS 3.3 Alpha

Tags: rubygems, installation, sass

Every time I try to install latest pre version of SASS

```
gem install sass --pre
```

return this output in terminal

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing sass:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/ruby.h


Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/ffi-1.9.0 for inspection.
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Install the pre-released version manually. Use `gem install sass --version=3.3.0.alpha.184`. If you're on a mac, you might need to use `sudo`.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error and this worked for me like a charm :)

[Failed to build gem native extension — Rails install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12552929/failed-to-build-gem-native-extension-rails-install)