# Failed to build gem native extension (mkmf (LoadError)) - Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ubuntu-12.04

Hey I'm trying to install rails on a new ubuntu machine. I have ruby and rvm installed but I'm getting a "failed to build gem native extension" error. What does this mean?

```
$ sudo gem install rails -v 3.2.9
```

(without the sudo says I don't have permissions)

Then it outputs a lot of 'fetching' commands and ultimately this error:

```
    Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
    ERROR:  Error installing rails:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

            /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 extconf.rb
    /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- mkmf (LoadError)
        from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
        from extconf.rb:1:in `<main>'


    Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.0 for inspection.
    Results logged to /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.0/ext/json/ext/generator/gem_make.out
```

When I type

```
$rails server
```

It says rails is not currently installed

Comment: Have you seen [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12552929/failed-to-build-gem-native-extension-rails-install?rq=1)

Comment: you should not use `sudo` with rvm!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Possible duplicate of:

[Unable to install gem - Failed to build gem native extension - cannot load such file -- mkmf (LoadError)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13767725/unable-to-install-gem-failed-to-build-gem-native-extension-cannot-load-such/13767801#13767801)

**Depending on your ruby version**, run:

```
sudo apt-get install ruby1.9.1-dev
```

Comment: -1 explanation please?

Comment: user installed ruby with `rvm`, using `sudo` switches him out of rvm installed ruby (resets environment variables), your solution does not explain anything of that only sets user to continue the `sudo` path

Comment: @mpapis I had this issue a long time before and fixed it with this command. Also the answer I linked (as the one that AlthafHamez linked) proves that it can solve the problem of mkmf LoadError. Where is your answer explaining how to fix this and why it does not work?

Comment: I did not down vote because I know better, I did it because it is confusing user

Answer (score 5):

If you are using RVM, you shouldn't ever be using 'sudo'. Using sudo calls libs and such out of the rvm path. Try just a flat:

```
gem install rails -v3.2.9
```

and see if that helps.

Comment: Mother of God this should have been the answer. Praise be to thee!